# Decreasing hight of header

Tags: html, css

I have created a responsive website using a software named 'Artisteer'. I have created a header which is slightly long in height and have a logo which is actually 'text' . It works perfect in desktop browsers but in mobile browser the header feels so longer. I tried to make it shorter by changing the height of header in responsive code, It worked. But the logo(which is actually text) is still at its original position. I want to decrease the distance between the top of the header and the logo. I tried changing the values in .art-headline and .art-slogan, but it didn't seem to work.

**Here is the screenshot when I changed the height of header**
[image]

**Here is the actual responsive view**
http://www.responsinator.com/?url=www.secondgf.com%2F

**Here is the Responsive coding**

```
/* Created by Artisteer v4.3.0.60745 */
  .responsive body
  {
    min-width: 240px;
  }
  .responsive img 
  {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }  
  .responsive .art-content-layout img,
  .responsive .art-content-layout video
  {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
  }
  .responsive.responsive-phone .art-content-layout img 
  {
    margin: 1%;
  }
  .responsive.responsive-phone .art-collage,
  .responsive.responsive-tablet .art-collage {
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
  .responsive .art-content-layout .art-sidebar0, 
  .responsive .art-content-layout .art-sidebar1, 
  .responsive .art-content-layout .art-sidebar2 
  {
    width: auto !important;
  }
  .responsive .art-content-layout, 
  .responsive .art-content-layout-row, 
  .responsive .art-layout-cell 
  {
    display: block;
  }
  .responsive .art-content-layout, 
  .responsive .art-content-layout-row
  {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .responsive .image-caption-wrapper 
  {
    width: auto;
  }
  .responsive.responsive-tablet .art-vmenublock,
  .responsive.responsive-tablet .art-block
  {
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .responsive .art-responsive-embed 
  {
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    /* 16:9 */
    position: relative;
  }
  .responsive .art-responsive-embed iframe,
  .responsive .art-responsive-embed object,
  .responsive .art-responsive-embed embed
  {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .responsive .art-header 
  {
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    min-height: 100px !important;
    min-width: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 2%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .default-responsive .art-header 
  {
    height: auto;
  }
  .default-responsive .art-header *
  {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
    -moz-transform: none !important;
    -o-transform: none !important;
    -ms-transform: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
  }
  .default-responsive .art-header .art-headline, 
  .default-responsive .art-header .art-slogan 
  {
    display: block !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    margin: 2% !important;
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  .default-responsive .art-header .art-headline a, 
  .default-responsive .art-header .art-slogan 
  {
    white-space: normal !important;
  }
  .default-responsive .art-header .art-logo
  {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto !important;
    left: auto;
    top: auto !important;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  .responsive .art-header .art-slidenavigator 
  {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .default-responsive .art-header .art-positioncontrol 
  {
    display: block !important;
    position: relative !important;
    top: auto !important;
    right: auto !important;
    bottom: auto !important;
    left: auto !important;
    margin: 2% auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
  }
  .responsive .art-header #art-flash-area
  {
    display: none;
  }
  /* Search and other elements in header element directly */
  .default-responsive .art-header&gt;.art-textblock
  {
    position: relative !important;
    display: block !important;
    margin: 1% auto !important;
    width: 75% !important;
    top: auto !important;
    right: auto !important;
    bottom: auto !important;
    left: auto !important;
  }
  .default-responsive .art-header .art-textblock 
  {
    position: relative !important;
    display: block !important;
    margin: auto !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    top: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto;
    background-image: none;
  }
  /* &#39;.art-header *&#39; used noram align, but for &#39;.art-textblock *&#39; we must force align because of preview */
  .responsive .art-header .art-textblock *
  {
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  .default-responsive .art-header .art-shapes &gt; .art-textblock,
  .default-responsive .art-header .art-slide-item &gt; .art-textblock
  {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .default-responsive .art-header .art-shapes &gt; .art-textblock *
  {
    text-align: center !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    display: block;
  }
  .default-responsive .art-header .art-slider .art-textblock *
  {
    text-align: center !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    display: block;
  }
  /* For icons like facebook, rss, etc. */
  .responsive .art-header&gt;.art-textblock&gt;div 
  {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .responsive .art-sheet
  {
    width: auto !important;
    min-width: 240px !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    margin-right: 1% !important;
    margin-left: 1% !important;
    margin-top: 1% !important;
  }
  #art-resp {
    display: none;
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 1009px)
    {
    #art-resp, #art-resp-t { display: block; }
    #art-resp-m { display: none; }
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 480px)
    {
    #art-resp, #art-resp-m { display: block; }
    #art-resp-t { display: none; }
  }
  #art-resp-desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  #art-resp-tablet-landscape {
    display: none;
  }
  #art-resp-tablet-portrait {
    display: none;
  }
  #art-resp-phone-landscape {
    display: none;
  }
  #art-resp-phone-portrait {
    display: none;
  }
  @media (min-width: 1200px)
    {
    #art-resp-desktop { display: block; }
  }
  @media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px)
    {
    #art-resp-tablet-landscape { display: block; }
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)
    {
    #art-resp-tablet-portrait { display: block; }
  }
  @media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)
    {
    #art-resp-phone-landscape { display: block; }
  }
  @media (max-width: 479px)
    {
    #art-resp-phone-portrait { display: block; }
  }
  .responsive .art-content-layout, 
  .responsive .art-content-layout-row, 
  .responsive .art-layout-cell 
  {
    display: block;
  }
  .responsive .art-layout-cell 
  {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
  }
  .responsive .art-content-layout:after, 
  .responsive .art-content-layout-row:after, 
  .responsive .art-layout-cell:after 
  {
    content: &quot;.&quot;;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .responsive .responsive-tablet-layout-cell,
  .responsive.responsive-tablet .art-footer .art-content-layout .art-layout-cell 
  {
    margin: 1%;
    width: 98% !important;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .responsive .responsive-layout-row-2 .responsive-tablet-layout-cell,
  .responsive.responsive-tablet .art-footer .art-content-layout .responsive-layout-row-2 .art-layout-cell
  {
    width: 48% !important;
  }
  .responsive .responsive-layout-row-3 .responsive-tablet-layout-cell,
  .responsive.responsive-tablet .art-footer .art-content-layout .responsive-layout-row-3 .art-layout-cell
  {
    width: 31% !important;
  }
  .responsive .art-post
  {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .responsive .art-footer-inner
  {
    min-width: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding responsive markup for the logo position at the same breakpoint as the header bars breakpoint?

Keep in mind that changing the layout of a parent does not always impact the layout of the child. It depends on what positioning attributes you use on both the parent and child. This is especially true if you are not targeting the exact same nodes in each breakpoint.

Comment: The text of the header is being pushed down by that widget with the icons in it with a class of `art-header-widget`. I would hide it on a small device, but you could also style it so that it didn't take up so much space on a small device.

Comment: `!important` *hisssssssss*. I would strongly suggest that you try out going into devtools and check whether your rules still apply if you remove the `!important` annotation. If they do, leave it out. Future CSS development becomes a huge battle of priorities when someone brings an atom bomb in round one.

Comment: @MatthewDarnell you are right. It worked. I just changed the position of the widget and it worked. Thank You. Thank you guys for giving me your precious time.

Comment: @MatthewDarnell . I disabled the widget in phone and tablet by  adding `.responsive.responsive-tablet .social
      {
        display: none;
      }
      .responsive.responsive-phone .social
      {
        display: none;
      }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS line :
    `.social { position : absolute; }` or `.social { position : fixed; }`

It will put this bar "outside" the document to erase the margin you see.

The "fixed" position will show this bar at the same position if you scroll down.

As you said, to disable it in phone and tablet you can do :

```
.responsive.responsive-tablet .social { display: none; } .responsive.responsive-phone .social { display: none; }
```

Comment: Thanx. I disabled the widget in phone and tablet by  adding `.responsive.responsive-tablet .social
      {
        display: none;
      }
      .responsive.responsive-phone .social
      {
        display: none;
      }`

Comment: Another question! I want use a jquery plugin called 'Headhesiv'.  Here is demo [HEADHESIVE](https://markgoodyear.com/labs/headhesive) . After some scrolling a secondary but fixed header appears. I tried many times but no luck. Can you help me???

Answer (score 0):

I cant help much with this since I do not know which classes did you add to the actual header. I looked through the web inspector at your header and it seems that you have the height of the header set to 100%, I am not sure since I do now know the full CSS.

Try this in your header:

```
max-height: 100%;
display: table
```

If you do this, then the header will only ever expand to 100% of the screen size if there are that many elements, but since it is displayed table, then the div will collapse to be large enough to fit the elements inside of it and no bigger. This is good for responsive design since divs shrink and stretch depending on screen size.

Answer (score 0):

replace this css and will solve issue.

```
.social {
    height: 220px;
    margin-top: 220px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    position: fixed !important;
    width: 200px;
}
```